# How to execute programs on mounted partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, fstab

This is the aplication I want to run.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuel manuel 582841 Nov 22 09:51 PromServerMain
```

This is the fstab entry

```
/dev/sda8 /media/data0 ext4 defaults,user 0 2
```

This is the mountpoint

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 manuel manuel     5 Nov 16 14:23 data -> data0
drwxrwxr-x 9 manuel manuel  4096 Nov 22 09:26 data0
```

This is what I get

```
manuel@P5KC /media/data/Projekte/PromServer/src $ ./PromServerMain
bash: ./PromServerMain: Keine Berechtigung
manuel@P5KC /media/data/Projekte/PromServer/src $ sudo ./PromServerMain
sudo: unable to execute ./PromServerMain: Permission denied
```

Even as root. I have no clue whats wrong. Any suggestions? System is Debian Wheezy Xfce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/media/data0` is mounted with `user` option. That implies `noexec` so it is not allowed to run executables from the filesystem. You have to add `exec`:

```
/dev/sda8 /media/data0 ext4 defaults,user,exec 0 2
```

or remove the `user` option.

Answer (score 0):

"Permission denied" on an executable is often a misleading error message, unfortunately.

Firstly, is this a real executable or a script? If it's a script then the interpreter (`#!/bin/whatever` line at the top) may be wrong, itself broken or lacking permissions, or there is a stray carriage return at the end of the line.

If it's a real executable, run `ldd PromServerMain` and post the output. One of the required libraries is probably missing or broken.

Comment: `manuel@P5KC /media/data0/Projekte/PromServer/src $ ldd PromServerMain: not a dynamic executable` But it is a executable. I compiled it . And it runs in other directories.